# Proof of Steinitz-Exchange-Theorem

Tags: linear-algebra

I cant figure out how to prove the Steinitz-Exchange-Theorem:

Let V be a vector space and $n,m \in \mathbb{N}^+, B = \{\vec{e_1},...,\vec{e_n}\}$ form a Basis of V with $A = \{\vec{v_1},...,\vec{v_m}\}$ linearly independant, then $m \leq n$ with $k_1,...,k_m \in \{1,...,n\}$ so that:
$$\tilde{B} = (B\setminus\{\vec{e_1},...,\vec{e_n}\}) \cup A$$

Thank you for any answers.

Comment: I think is a typo in your question: if $B = \{ e_1, \ldots, e_n \}$ then $B \backslash \{ e_1, \ldots, e_n \} = \emptyset$ and so $\tilde{B}=A$.

Comment: See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steinitz_exchange_lemma.